# Run a bat file on several remote desktop only from console

Tags: c#, console, remote-access, remote-desktop, vnc

I am going to run a bat file over more than 10 remote desktops. It is important that the user not getting confused. And he should just look around a waiting bar to get complete.
I checked PSEXEC and it failed in some case. For admin$ or some other reasons.
Then rdp+ and it doesn't work for me.
Now, would you please tell me if running a CMD command like this could work?

mstsc /v: computer1 /console /admin /password /start:file.bat

Or using VNC to run this bat file.

Comment: in which case does psexec fail?

Comment: While the registry key for the remote host computer was set to 0. I didn't know how to change it by code.

Comment: does it has any relationship with remote?

Comment: My usres are going to load a list of thier remote desktops. And the app should run bat file on them all